# Ruby on Rails -- Error rendering partial twice while passing two different variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use a form partial for multiple sections within a page. The first time, I'm passing "section: "o"", and the second time I'm passing "section: "s"".

It works successfully when I pass the first variable, but the second time the form partial is rendered, it generates an "undefined method `humanize' for nil:NilClass" error.

Here's an example of the form that's rendering an additional partial:

```
<some form stuff here>
<%= render partial: "item_form", locals: {f: f, section: "o"} %>
<some form stuff here>
<%= render partial: "item_form", locals: {f: f, section: "s"} %>
```

And here's part of the _item_form.html.erb partial that's being rendered:

```
  <% unless @item.paragraphs.empty? %>
    <% @item.paragraphs.each do |paragraph| %>
      <% field_type = "Paragraph" if paragraph.paragraph_type == "#{section}paragraph" %>
      <% field_type = "Figure description" if paragraph.paragraph_type == "#{section}figure" %>
      <% field_type = "Bullet" if paragraph.paragraph_type == "#{section}bullet" %>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label field_type, class: "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
```

The error that I get highlights the f.label line (last line in the example above) and spits out the error "undefined method `humanize' for nil:NilClass".

Any idea what's going on here? If I remove the first render, it still doesn't work. If I remove the first render and change the second section to "o" instead of "s", then it works. Adding in any other letter other than "o" for the section screws it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field_type is only defined on certain situations, as you can see in your code:

```
<% field_type = "Paragraph" if paragraph.paragraph_type == "#{section}paragraph" %>
<% field_type = "Figure description" if paragraph.paragraph_type == "#{section}figure" %>
<% field_type = "Bullet" if paragraph.paragraph_type == "#{section}bullet" %>
```

Are you sure that at least one of them are always true?

My guess is that you do have a paragraph with type oparagraph, ofigure or obullet, but not with type sparagraph, sfigure or sbullet, so in the end you're going to have a nil field_type.

I don't know the business logic behind you app, but I would suggest to define a standard case (if you can, of course) and then update it when necessary, like:

```
<% field_type = "Paragraph" %>
<% field_type = "Figure description" if paragraph.paragraph_type == "#{section}figure" %>
<% field_type = "Bullet" if paragraph.paragraph_type == "#{section}bullet" %>
```

I would also suggest to move this logic to a helper, instead of deciding the field label name in the view itself.

Comment: Ahh ok. I didn't catch that it was complaining about field_type for some reason. Thought it was complaining about f. Thanks for your suggestion. Going to take that route now. I think I can fix this based on your help. Thanks again